# Saving result of has_one association to avoid fetching DB in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, optimization, model, has-one

I have a `has_one` association between **User** model and **Player** model.  I see myself doing current_user.player so many times in controllers and views, and I feel like I am hitting the DB way too much every time I do that.  Also it would be nice to have a current_player method.

How and where would I define a method like that so I can access `current_player` from both the controllers and the views?

Answer (score 0):

It's (properly) going to reload at least once each time you hit the page, but you can help prevent following loads by [memoizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the result:

```
class User
  has_one :player
  def current_player
    @current_player ||= player
  end
end
```

As an alternative, you could possibly include the player model
in the default scope, so it loads whenever the User model is loaded:

```
class User
  has_one :player
  default_scope includes(:player)
end
```

Unfortunately, whenever I've tried that I tend to quickly find I actually didn't want it auto-loading the other table *every* time, and switch back to the previous method which only loads from the 2nd table on first use. Simply memoizing the object into an ivar is vastly more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That would make me fetch the current player by doing current_user.current_player. How would I just access current_player from both the controller and the views?